# Too high reputation shown in header

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I noticed today that my reputation is shown incorrectly -- too high -- in the header:

[image]

This was shown on a browser tab I opened a few days ago. I remember that I earned some 15 points on one of the last few days, maybe that is the reason behind the 15 point difference.

If I refresh the page the counter in the header shows the correct value:

[image]

My reputation history doesn't show any reputation decrease for the last half year:
[image]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an accepted, then unaccepted answer or +15 rep change immediately reverted.

The rep tab will increase using AJAX requests but won't decrease if there is a rep-drop.

You saw 379 because someone accepted your answer / you may get 3 upvote on question / you may get 2 upvote, 1 on question and 1 on answer.

Then the rep tab increased to 379.

But if it changed immediately, you can't see it in achievements tab.

But the increased value will stay there until you refresh the page.

Comment: Sagar, thanks for the explanation. I was not considering that notification bar may behave differently for increase and decrease.

Comment: It is. It only refresh if there is a +change. for -change, it won't decrease until you reload the page.

Comment: Sagar, I checked my reputation history, and there's no -15 change for the last half year. Shouldn't be there a +15 followed by -15 for?

Comment: If the accept and unaccept happen within some period, it will not shown I think. It may happen within seconds

Comment: That seems reasonable. Thanks again!